# CSS hack for Firefox 3 Mac

Tags: css, macos, firefox

Without doing a lot, I need to make a height in my CSS class be 570px on PC, but 610px on Firefox on Mac. Is there a quick and easy CSS hack for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using something like http://snipplr.com/view/625/browser-detect-lite--v21/
to detect which browser/OS the client is using, and from that attach classes to the HTML or BODY tag on load stating the browser (+ version) and OS.

then on your stylesheet you could do (for example):

```
 .win.ff3 #whatever { height: 570px; }
 .mac.ff3 #whatever { height: 610px; }
```